# Mac OS X gem debug_inspector installation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

I'm running ruby version 2.3.0 trying to install the debug_inspector gem but getting:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/Archerdog1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/debug_inspector-0.0.2
```

any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to `chown` your `.rbenv` directory?

Comment: like: chown user_name .rbenv

Comment: You would want to make it recursive, so `sudo chown -R Archerdog1 /Users/Archerdog1/.rbenv`